# Converting Shared Preferences saved ArrayList JSON String back to usable object throws null pointer for Activity?

Tags: java, android, json, listview, arraylist

**High-level context**

I was trying to get my ListView to update each time the user Resumes the application, when I noticed this Exception thrown in Debug.

`ArrayList<Flow> FlowManager` is saved in *SharedPreferences*
 and retrieved `onResume()` to populate the *listView* using a Custom Array Adapter (`FlowArrayAdapter`)

The thrown null pointer is caught (see debug picture), but I wanted to know if there were any ideas why the NullPointerException would be thrown for `this` at that line in the first place?

Isn't `this`== to the current Activity (`TheStream.Activity`) and therefore an object and therefore not `null`?

**Caught Exception** 
[image]
[image]

*Code if curious:*

**TheStream.java**

```
public class TheStream extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Flow newFlow; //Blank flow object declared.

    private static ArrayList<Flow> flowManager;

    private FlowArrayAdapter helperAdapter;
    private ListView listView;

    /** UI Actions and Set up */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_stream);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.streamFeed);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        populateList();
        setItemOnClicks();

    }

   private void populateList() {

    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Retrieving flowManager data...");
        SharedPreferences mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        // Convert JSON Object stored as STRING in Shared Prefs, back to
        // Useable ArrayList Collection

        String json = mPrefs.getString("flowManager", null);

               // >>> NULLPOINTER THROWN + CAUGHT HERE 
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Flow>>() {}.getType();
              // >>> NULLPOINTER THROWN  + CAUGHT HERE 

        flowManager = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception throw in populating list: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    if (flowManager==null) {
        flowManager = new ArrayList<Flow>();
    }

    helperAdapter = new FlowArrayAdapter(this, flowManager);
    listView.setAdapter(helperAdapter);

    helperAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**FlowArrayAdapter.Java**

```
public class FlowArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Flow> {
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView elements;
    TextView timeEstimate;
}

public FlowArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Flow> Flows) {
    super(context, R.layout.flow_item_in_stream, Flows);
} // End of constructor

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.flow_item_in_stream, parent, false);


        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_flow_name);
        holder.elements = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_element_count);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    // Get the data item for this position
    Flow flow = getItem(position);

    // Populate the data into the template view using the data from Flow object

    holder.name.setText(String.valueOf(flow.getName()));

    holder.elements.setText(String.valueOf(flow.getElementCount()));

    return convertView;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String json = mPrefs.getString("flowManager", null);
```

this will return null if "flowManager" key isnt found in shared prefs. as the second parameter in the method call is the defualt returned value. so if you want to avoid null pointer do a null  check before trying to use the "json" variable. you need to also call .apply() on  ShredPreferences.Editor  before it will be saved. example

```
presfEditor.putString("flowManager", json).apply();
```